# Use setstate to change dictionary, but not working. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, react-hooks, use-state

```
const [days, setDays] = useState({ Monday: false, Tuesday: false,Wednesday: false,Thursday: false, Friday: false,Saturday: false,Sunday:false });

const [traildays, setTrialDays] = useState('MON,WED,THUR,SAT');

const Changedays = async () => { 
        if(traildays.includes('MON') == true) {setDays({...days,Monday:!days.Monday})}
        if(traildays.includes('TUE') == true) {setDays({...days,Tuesday:!days.Tuesday})}
        if(traildays.includes('WED') == true) {setDays({...days,Wednesday:!days.Wednesday})}
        if(traildays.includes('THUR') == true) {setDays({...days,Thursday:!days.Thursday})}
        if(traildays.includes('FRI') == true) {setDays({...days,Friday:!days.Friday})}
        if(traildays.includes('SAT') == true) {setDays({...days,Saturday:!days.Saturday})}
        if(traildays.includes('SUN') == true) {setDays({...days,Sunday:!days.Sunday})}
```

This is the gist of it where I want to change the true and false of each day depending on if it was mentioned in the `traildays` string. What ends of happening is only Saturday changes to true.

[image]

I think it has something to do with the ...days resetting everything but any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, each setter uses same days value from `const [days, setDays]` and overrides one field of it. Please try handy form of `setDays(prevValue => newValue)` instead. As an argument you receive the latest model state, so can apply your changes incrementally:

```
if(traildays.includes('MON') == true) {
  setDays(prevDays => {
    return {...prevDays, Monday:!days.Monday};
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what @udalmik said, or you might want to set the state once to not make any unnecesary rerenders

```
  const [days, setDays] = useState({
    Monday: false,
    Tuesday: false,
    Wednesday: false,
    Thursday: false,
    Friday: false,
    Saturday: false,
    Sunday: false,
  });

  const [traildays, setTrialDays] = useState('MON,WED,THUR,SAT');

  useEffect(() => {
    setDays({
      Monday: traildays.includes('MON'),
      Tuesday: traildays.includes('TUE'),
      Wednesday: traildays.includes('WED'),
      Thursday: traildays.includes('THUR'),
      Friday: traildays.includes('FRI'),
      Saturday: traildays.includes('SAT'),
      Sunday: traildays.includes('SUN'),
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thank you, that's very useful